# React FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory error on AWS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am developing a web application with React and I want to deploy it via AWS Amplify. I measure the heap_size used by this application as 4144 on my own computer using the `node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))` command. Accordingly, I updated my npm build command as follows:

```
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "build": "react-scripts build --max_old_space_size=16384",
     ...
   },
```

However, I still get the following result in the AWS Amplify terminal. What solution can be offered for this?

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: yarn install
2023-11-02T09:35:28.415Z [INFO]: yarn install v1.22.0
2023-11-02T09:35:28.433Z [INFO]: info No lockfile found.
2023-11-02T09:35:28.442Z [INFO]: [1/4] Resolving packages...
2023-11-02T09:35:33.045Z [WARNING]: warning babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
2023-11-02T09:35:36.593Z [WARNING]: warning node-sass > make-fetch-happen > cacache > @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
                                    warning node-sass > node-gyp > make-fetch-happen > cacache > @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
2023-11-02T09:35:37.955Z [WARNING]: warning react-drag-listview > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
2023-11-02T09:35:38.389Z [WARNING]: warning react-image-lightbox@5.1.4: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
2023-11-02T09:35:38.749Z [WARNING]: warning react-jvectormap@0.0.16: This package is deprecated. Please start using @react-jvectormap/core instead
2023-11-02T09:35:39.835Z [WARNING]: warning Resolution field "autoprefixer@10.4.5" is incompatible with requested version "autoprefixer@^10.4.13"
2023-11-02T09:35:39.942Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:39.990Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > babel-preset-react-app > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
2023-11-02T09:35:40.012Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > babel-preset-react-app > @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
2023-11-02T09:35:40.015Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > babel-preset-react-app > @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
2023-11-02T09:35:40.017Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > babel-preset-react-app > @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
2023-11-02T09:35:40.021Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > babel-preset-react-app > @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
2023-11-02T09:35:41.061Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:41.622Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
2023-11-02T09:35:42.258Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
2023-11-02T09:35:42.258Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
2023-11-02T09:35:42.572Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
2023-11-02T09:35:42.602Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-background-sync@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.605Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-broadcast-update@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.623Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.623Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-background-sync > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-broadcast-update > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.624Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-expiration@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.624Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-expiration > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.625Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.1: workbox-background-sync@6.6.1
2023-11-02T09:35:42.626Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-cacheable-response > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.631Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-google-analytics@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.632Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-google-analytics > workbox-background-sync@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.632Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-google-analytics > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.633Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-precaching@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.634Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-precaching > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.639Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-navigation-preload@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.639Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-navigation-preload > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.644Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.645Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes > workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.1: workbox-background-sync@6.6.1
2023-11-02T09:35:42.645Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes > workbox-expiration@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes > workbox-precaching@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.652Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-routing@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.652Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-google-analytics > workbox-routing@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-precaching > workbox-routing@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes > workbox-routing@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.652Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-routing > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.655Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-strategies@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.655Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-google-analytics > workbox-strategies@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-precaching > workbox-strategies@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
                                    warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-recipes > workbox-strategies@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.656Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-strategies > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.657Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-range-requests@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.657Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-range-requests > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.659Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-sw@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.660Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-window@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.661Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-window > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.665Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-streams@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.666Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-streams > workbox-core@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.666Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > workbox-streams > workbox-routing@6.6.1: this package has been deprecated
2023-11-02T09:35:42.928Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
2023-11-02T09:35:42.928Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > css-minimizer-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
2023-11-02T09:35:43.590Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @surma/rollup-plugin-off-main-thread > magic-string > sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
2023-11-02T09:35:43.694Z [WARNING]: warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
2023-11-02T09:35:46.638Z [WARNING]: warning @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.
2023-11-02T09:35:46.818Z [INFO]: [2/4] Fetching packages...
2023-11-02T09:36:22.776Z [INFO]: info fsevents@2.3.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
                                 info "fsevents@2.3.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2023-11-02T09:36:22.790Z [INFO]: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
2023-11-02T09:36:22.792Z [WARNING]: warning " > autoprefixer@10.4.5" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.1.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.793Z [WARNING]: warning " > @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@6.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core@>=37.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.793Z [WARNING]: warning " > @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@6.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine@>=37.0.0".
                                    warning " > @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@6.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils@>=37.0.0".
                                    warning " > @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@6.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog@>=37.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.795Z [WARNING]: warning " > @testing-library/user-event@14.5.1" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.795Z [WARNING]: warning " > autoprefixer@10.4.16" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.1.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.795Z [WARNING]: warning " > bootstrap@5.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@popperjs/core@^2.11.7".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.798Z [WARNING]: warning " > google-maps-react@2.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "react@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.798Z [WARNING]: warning " > google-maps-react@2.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.798Z [WARNING]: warning " > nouislider-react@3.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "nouislider@>= 11.x".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.799Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-chartjs-2@2.11.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.799Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-chartjs-2@2.11.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.800Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-draft-wysiwyg@1.15.0" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@3.x.x || 4.x.x".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.801Z [WARNING]: warning "react-draft-wysiwyg > draftjs-utils@0.10.2" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@3.x.x || 4.x.x".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.801Z [WARNING]: warning "react-draft-wysiwyg > html-to-draftjs@1.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@3.x.x || 4.x.x".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.801Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-image-lightbox@5.1.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.x || 17.x".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.801Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-image-lightbox@5.1.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@16.x || 17.x".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.802Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-json-view@1.21.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^17.0.0 || ^16.3.0 || ^15.5.4".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.802Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-json-view@1.21.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.0 || ^16.3.0 || ^15.5.4".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.802Z [WARNING]: warning "react-json-view > flux@4.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.0.2 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.803Z [WARNING]: warning " > react-rangeslider@2.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.807Z [WARNING]: warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.807Z [WARNING]: warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.811Z [WARNING]: warning "react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.812Z [WARNING]: warning "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object > @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@7.22.15" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.814Z [WARNING]: warning "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object > @babel/plugin-syntax-private-property-in-object@7.14.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.817Z [WARNING]: warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
2023-11-02T09:36:22.821Z [WARNING]: warning " > @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2023-11-02T09:37:05.361Z [INFO]: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
2023-11-02T09:37:25.708Z [INFO]: success Saved lockfile.
2023-11-02T09:37:25.711Z [INFO]: Done in 117.30s.
2023-11-02T09:37:25.799Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-11-02T09:37:25.800Z [INFO]: # Executing command: yarn run build
2023-11-02T09:37:25.925Z [INFO]: yarn run v1.22.0
2023-11-02T09:37:25.947Z [INFO]: $ react-scripts build --max_old_space_size=8192
2023-11-02T09:37:26.943Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2023-11-02T09:42:15.643Z [WARNING]: <--- Last few GCs --->
                                    [1450:0x542dbe0]   287958 ms: Scavenge 2023.0 (2080.5) -> 2022.5 (2082.0) MB, 2.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.687, current mu = 0.176) allocation failure
                                    [1450:0x542dbe0]   287965 ms: Scavenge 2024.1 (2082.0) -> 2023.6 (2091.7) MB, 5.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.687, current mu = 0.176) allocation failure
                                    [1450:0x542dbe0]   289631 ms: Mark-sweep 2031.3 (2092.5) -> 2027.4 (2097.7) MB, 1658.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.492, current mu = 0.022) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
                                    <--- JS stacktrace --->
                                    FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2023-11-02T09:42:15.645Z [WARNING]: 1: 0xb08e80 node::Abort() [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
                                    2: 0xa1b70e  [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.645Z [WARNING]: 3: 0xce1890 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.646Z [WARNING]: 4: 0xce1c37 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.646Z [WARNING]: 5: 0xe992a5  [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.647Z [WARNING]: 6: 0xea8f6d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.648Z [WARNING]: 7: 0xeabc6e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.648Z [WARNING]: 8: 0xe6d1aa v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.648Z [WARNING]: 9: 0x11e5f96 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:15.649Z [WARNING]: 10: 0x15d9c19  [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node]
2023-11-02T09:42:26.630Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with exit code 1.
2023-11-02T09:42:26.692Z [INFO]: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2023-11-02T09:42:26.792Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-11-02T09:42:26.812Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-11-02T09:42:26.812Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-11-02T09:42:26.828Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-11-02T09:42:26.912Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-11-02T09:42:26.912Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Comment: You're running out of memory. I would recommend not using react-scripts but a more modern bundler that doesn't require as much memory, e.g. https://vitejs.dev/ ...

Comment: You can also try the `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` envvar if you can live without source maps; generating them is generally memory-intensive.